# Import JSON file as const in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, import

I would like to create a union type from a property of the elements of an array.
If the array were inline, that would be pretty straightforward using a constant assertion.

```
const arr = [{ "name": "One" }, { "name": "Two" }] as const;

type name = typeof arr[number]["name"];
// name = "One" | "Two"
```

Note that without `as const` the type `name` becomes equal to `string`, which is not the intent.

The problem I'm facing is that the array is defined in a separate JSON file.
I set `"resolveJsonModule": true` in the TypeScript options so I can import the JSON file in my module.
But then the compiler widens the type of all properties in the array as there is no `as const` on the definition.

```
import * as arr from "./array.json";

type name = typeof arr[number]["name"];
// name = string (!)
```

Is there a way I can import a JSON file without type widening?

Comment: To get the name attribute of the first element, you should be using `arr[<idx>].name`

Answer (score 12):

I needed an answer to this too, and then realized, "Hey, that wouldn't be a hard npm package to write."

I don't *believe* there is a pure TS way to do this.  The package I created is called [`ts-json-as-const`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-json-as-const).

```sh
npm install -D ts-json-as-const
npx ts-json-as-const ./path/to/file.json ./path/to/second/file.json
```

###### Example JSON file (`example.json`)

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": false,
    "baz": true,
    "i-can": "hascheezburger"
  },
  "array": [ 1, 2, 3, { "foo": 1, "bar": [ 4, 5 ] }, 6 ]
}
```

###### Output `example.json.d.ts`

```ts
interface Example {
  foo: {
    bar: false;
    baz: true;
    'i-can': 'hascheezburger';
  },
  array: [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    {
      foo: 1;
      bar: [
        4,
        5
      ]
    },
    6
  ]
}

declare const Example: Example;

export = Example;
```

I'll admit, the array spacing isn't great, but who looks at .d.ts files for their json files anyway?

Comment: Thank you for this, though it is annoying that it is necessary! Why wouldn't TS import it `as const` by default :(

Answer (score -6):

https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

example.json:

```json
{
    "name": "testing"
}
```

javascript:

```js
// ES6/ES2015
// app.js

import * as data from './example.json';

const word = data.name;

console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

or In Typescript, however, the same code will throw error:

Cannot find module 'example.json'

[UPDATE] Solution: Typescript 2.9 supports JSON import!

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true  
  }
}
```