# Use JSON's key value as the type to auto suggest within the function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

So let's say I have the data like this:

```
{
   "key1": "hardcoded string",
   "key2": "another hardcoded string",
}
```

I have a function with 2 parameters where first parameter should point to the key1 and the other to that key's value.

For example:

```
funcName('key1', 'hardcoded string')
```

And the function just basically works like this:

```
funcName(key, defaultValue) {
   return jsonData[key] || defaultValue
}
```

Now to get key to auto suggest the JSON's key works fine if I do something like this:

```
import data from './data.json'

type JsonData = typeof data

funcName<K extends keyof JsonData>(key: K, defaultValue: JsonData[K]) {
   return jsonData[key] || defaultValue
}
```

Now when I try to pass to the `funcName` first parameter, I get suggested key1, key2, but when I set that parameter lets say to key1, I want the second parameter to suggest only 'hardcoded string'. Now the code above supposedly works, but I only get the type suggestions for the first parameter and not the second.

Can anyone give any suggestions how to make the second parameters to suggest the first parameters key value?

Comment: Are you talking about an IDE feature?

Comment: Are you ok with writing the type in your code or you are looking for TS to dynamically infer it?

Comment: @TusharShahi We have about 1k lines of prewritten json and we need to suggest that jsons keys and values as types basically, so yes ts should dynamically take them and suggest I suppose. The keys working okay, the values are not being suggested tho

Comment: Which IDE are you talking about? Code suggestions isn't a language feature.

Comment: @jabaa vscode. We have configured to get the types in alll our ts files and like I said it works fine with the keys from the code I listed in the question, the only problem is that the second param should auto suggest that keys value from json thats all

Comment: Your problem seems to be the rules for [Literal Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). The types are infered as `string`, not as literals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JSON file as const in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281175/import-json-file-as-const-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is type narrowing of your JSON.

Ideally something like this would have worked:

```typescript
import data from './data.json' as const;
```

`as const` is used for type [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and restricts widening of types. So the type of `data` would be inferred as

```typescript
{
  "key1": "hardcoded string",
  "key2": "another hardcoded string"
}
```

But looking at Github [threads](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063), this feature is not available yet.

One way or the other you will have to write the types out.

Either:

1. you write the type while importing or,
2. you create a declaration file for your JSON.

**Here is the second approach:**

First create a `data.d.json.ts`

```typescript
const data: {
  key1: 'hardcoded string';
  key2: 'another hardcoded string';
};

export default data;
```

Second, add the following key to `tsconfig.json` inside `compilerOptions`:

```json
"allowArbitraryExtensions" : true
```

From the docs of [`allowArbitraryExtensions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/it/tsconfig#allowArbitraryExtensions):

> ... when an import path ends in an extension that isn’t a known JavaScript or TypeScript file extension, the compiler will look for a declaration file for that path in the form of {file basename}.d.{extension}.ts. For example, if you are using a CSS loader in a bundler project, you might want to write (or generate) declaration files for those stylesheets:

What we have done is declared a type for your JSON and exposed it to the TypeScript compiler. It will refer to the new declaration file every time `data.json` is imported in a TS file. I used the most specific type.

The result should look like this:

[image: screenshot of IDE suggesting value]

**The first approach is of course this:**

```typescript
type JsonData = {
  key1: 'hardcoded string';
  key2: 'another hardcoded string';
};
```

Comment: So I have edited my question, because we have the whole data within the json where keys and values are within the double quates. 

Your solution doesnt seem to work in my case. I have tried adding the .ts file but even if that works we cant really have this as we have that json file updated with various values from other people every day, that means we would have 2 places to add these values from now on.  

Adding the flag to the tsconfig doesnt do anything as well. 
Thats all assuming that the function type declarations are the same as I wrote in the question

Comment: I sent you the example right from my IDE so it should work. Maybe reload vscode. `data.d.json.ts` should be named same as your json. And adding flag to config should work after that.

Comment: I get your concern though. There will be two sources of data. You can use some library that already does this, but then again they are probably doing the same thing, but automated

Comment: Yeah it could be various configurations set but I added the .d.json.ts file of my json file, added the flag but I dont get any suggestions at all for the value whatsoever. This was just a nice thing to have for our project, depending on other libraries is out of question. I thought it was pretty easy solution withing ts to do that since json has already typed values.